# Portion in olam haba and gilgulim

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, reincarnation

When the Mishna or Gemara says that someone has no portion in the world to come, is that referring to his body or soul?

In the context of belief in gilgulim, a soul can be reincarnated many times into various bodies. Let's say the soul gets reincarnated 5 times - the first 4 were mostly righteous but had to come back to fix something, but in the 5th he did something that caused him to lose his cheilek in olam haba. Does that mean the first 4 also lose it (since it's the same soul)? Or maybe somehow those four bodies get a portion in the world to come, since they were righteous - but if so what soul will they have?

Comment: Your final line is answered here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8334/.

Comment: According to the accepted answer there, it seems the soul gets portioned into components : "Ultimately, each component of the soul will be resurrected in the body which served as its host.". If so, then it's entirely plausible that here the components that were in the first four bodies will be resurrected with those bodies, while the 5th component (and body) will not be.

Comment: The Q is good and I +1ed it, but my sincere advice - consider all statements about Olam Habah as seeking educational goal only. Nobody truly knew or knows what it is, what a soul is, what reincarnation is and what T'hias Hameisim is either. Rabbis brought it to distant us from sinning. G-d has the exclusive right to decide on what will happen.

Comment: Acc. to Zohar, a Jewish soul can never be cut off because it never sins to its root, there's always a part that remains pure. So either a person is cut off but he's not a Jew or there's no cutting off for Jews and it's only a warning.

Comment: Great News, @Al Berko! What, then, is karet for us as Jews? May we go around comitting karet-level sins, secure in our knowledge that "there's no cutting off for a Jew"?

Comment: @JoshK sorry to spoil the party, please don't be mad. A large part of Rabbinical statements/speculations is educational, just like you warn your kids - if you stick your fingers in the socket you'll die, but you know he won't. the Gemmorah asks what the Kores is and provides a couple of options NONE of which includes cutting off. Zohar explains it's practically impossible for the [truly] Jewish soul. This follows the verse "אם אחפץ במות הרשע כי אם בשוב רשע מדרכו וחיה" - there's no point in losing a sinner but in repenting.

Comment: No party spoiled at all, @al, to the contrary. Please excuse me, I'm off to see some niddot lady friends, have to let them know *dod* Al said karet doesn't exist for Jews. Kol tuv!

Comment: @JoshK I didn't say Kores does not exist, please be exact, I said it's not what most laymen think - cutting off completely.

Comment: @JoshK see https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%AA#חז"ל

Comment: Maybe explain a bit more in detail, @Al, there are lurkers here who will take your words as halacha m'sinai

Comment: re the wiki : Some, having led a very bad life may not think that having it shortened is such a bad deal, given they may be reincarnated and won't be cut off. For some I don't know if the threat of being cut off even effectively deters iniquitousness. At least that is how it seems to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Kol israel yesh lahem heilek leoilom habo! All Jews have a portion in the world to come (vias haMoshaich). When it is written that there are those who don’t it means that those who don’t will also be resurrected and be in oilom habo, but they will be last to come to life. That would be considered as a punishment since everyone else will see that they came late and understand that it’s because of Aveiros. But tachles... All incarnations return.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. See in particular the focus on sources. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: A source would greatly enhance the validity of this answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say that someone lost his Olam Haba in the final moments of his life. Would you say it’s not fair to his first eight decades that his final one causes them to lose their portion? No - it’s the same person. If you accept the concept of reincarnation, you have to think about it similarly: we perceive them as five people scattered across time, but they’re actually the same person.

Comment: Well that was really my question - are reincarnated people the _same_ person scattered across time, or are they different people who happen to have the same soul. I suppose what underlies this is whether "a person" is just a soul, or a soul+body composite.

Comment: And speaking of fairness...It's actually not unreasonable to say that if one lives for 80 years as a really righteous person and then does one thing that causes them to lose their portion, that it's unfair to those 80 first years of his life and effort. Do you not agree?

Comment: @user9806 Such a person certainly won’t lose their reward earned over their life; they just won’t get it in the next world.

Comment: Where will he get that reward if not in the next world? (Remember, we're supposing he didn't yet get it in this world since, being righteous, he was slated for the world to come. And he can't/is unlikely to get it in this world, since he's already very old. (To make this point uncontested, we can assume he does the sin on the last day of his life).

Comment: @user9806 Hashem is able to do anything. He can give out one’s full reward even in his final day.

Comment: That's a catch all answer though. Hashem can also prevent him from sinning in the first place, or make it not count, or create a temporary clone of an olam haba to give him his reward, etc. etc. But if our discussion is to be within the parameters of "reasonable" or "plausible", it's not clear how 80 years worth of reward can be given out in one single day, especially since that reward would have been of an infinite quality (if he hadn't sinned) in a spiritual world. It's unclear what it's equivalent is in this physical world. But this is a whole other question.

Comment: @user Hashem could do whatever He wants, but He runs the world in a certain way. For someone who's sufficiently wicked, Hashem rewards him in this world. How He does that is up to Him, but it is done. Perhaps it's on his last day. Perhaps it's in a future lifetime, if you buy into reincarnation. But those are the rules which Hashem imposes on Himself, so to speak, in His dealings with our world.

Comment: Your answer is (seemingly wrongly) based on a common assumption that a whole soul is reincarnated. That would limit the number of possible Jews living simultaneously to 600K. As we see it is not true, therefore Ariz'L was right explaining that Gilgulim are not about whole souls but about part of souls. In such case it's illogical that only a part of a soul will be cut from the WTC.

Comment: @AlBerko I don’t think people generally assume that there are only 600K souls. I’m familiar with the concept of Nitzotzos, but not everyone who holds of Gilgulim holds of Nitzotzos.

Comment: @Al Berko there may be more souls waiting to come down. Just because there were 600k Jews at one point doesn’t mean there can never be more, it just means that not all of the souls are on earth yet.

Comment: @Loani Once again - define soul - is it a whole or parts of it also called a soul?

Comment: @Alberko Whole souls.