# What will happen to donated organs at techiyas hameisim?

Tags: resurrection-of-the-dead

If someone who will be reborn in techiyas hameisim donates their kidney, for example, to someone else who will be reborn in techiyas hameisim, who gets the kidney- the donor or the recipient? Or do they both miraculously get a kidney?

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109023/bodily-or-spiritual-resurrection.

Comment: A better question would be if someone was cut in half lengthwise, would both halves resurrect?
https://www.berfrois.com/uploads/2012/08/laser-James-Bond.jpg

Comment: @Harel13 See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8334, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26901, and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34126

Comment: Presumably, both the donor and the donee will get new kidneys the same way  any other corpse with long since decomposed organs will get new kidneys

Comment: @Schmerel the only difference is that the donor didn't have a kidney to begin with so he might not get one at techiyas hameisim of we are reborn the way we are buried.

Comment: Why do you assume people are reborn the exact way they are buried? If someone died in a horrible car crash will they come back disfigured? Is every amputee going to be missing organs after Techyias HaMeisim?

Comment: @Schmerel -- Depends on how you interpret this:  "As a man departs [this life] so will he be when he is resurrected. If he departs blind, he will return blind; if he departs deaf, he will return deaf; if he departs mute, he will return mute; if he departs lame, he will return lame; if he departs clothed, he will return clothed... God said, "Let them arise as they went, and afterwards I will heal them."  [Genesis R. 95:1; also Sanhedrin 91b]